# Why does my tar via ssh (command via authorized_keys) corrupt the archive?

Tags: linux, ssh, tar, authorized-keys

From a backup-machine I want to pull tgz dumps of a production server. Both machines run ubuntu 16.04.

Therefore, the backup-server connects via ssh and a specific ssh to to the production server.

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the respective user on the production server should just allow a single command and puts as much restrictions as possible (? I hope):

`command="tar -cz --file - --ignore-command-error --ignore-failed-read /dir/ 2>/dev/null | cat",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AABLASHKEY comment`

where `/dir/` is the directory to be backed up, `AABLASSHKEY` and `comment` are the "real" values of course.

The `| cat` is needed in this case because otherwise tar in that ubuntu version ("tar (GNU tar) 1.28") will not speak to the stdout given by ssh (PTY). The stderr should go into the void (`2> /dev/null`).
**Edit**: The point about PTY is a misconception, see the answer by @grawity.

On the receiving side (the `backup` server) I pick it up like the following:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key the-user@production-server > dir.tgz
```

However, the resulting file differs in size from the archive if I craete it on the server and is not a valid archive (e.g. `gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error ... gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error`). The size difference is 22 bytes.

If I allow the backup-server any command on the productive server by removing the restrictions in `authorized_keys` it works fine. What point do I miss?

**Constraints**

- I really want to use `tar` (not rsync, rrsync or something like that).
- The connection should be initiated by the backup-server
- The production server should not create any temporary files

**Solution**

As @Grawity pointed out in his answer (read it to clear some misconceptions), following line in `~.ssh/authorized_keys` solves the issue (and works on Ubuntu 16.04 with the given OpenSSH version):

```
command="tar -cz --file - --ignore-command-error --ignore-failed-read /dir/ 2>/dev/null",restrict ssh-rsa ....
```

To make the back-up-server command issue no warnings, connect with:

```
ssh -o RequestTTY=no -i /path/to/key the-user@production-server > dir.tgz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `| cat` is needed in this case because otherwise tar […] will not speak to the stdout given by ssh (PTY).

No. Having a PTY is precisely one of your problems. The tty layer exists to process terminal control characters and is not something you want *at all* for other kinds of data.

Normally running *ssh* in batch mode (i.e. `ssh <host> <cmd>`) will not allocate a PTY server-side; it will provide a 8-bit clean channel. But when you don't provide a command on the client, you need to explicitly add the `-T` or `RequestTTY` client option to disable the TTY request,

```
ssh -T theuser@prod > dir.tgz
ssh -o RequestTTY=no theuser@prod > dir.tgz
```

or provide a dummy command,

```
ssh theuser@prod foo > dir.tgz
```

or forbid such requests with the `no-pty` authorized_keys option:

```
command="tar -czf - /dir/ 2>/dev/null",no-pty,restrict ssh-rsa ABCDEF
```

*(`restrict` is a recently added alias which disables all forwardings at once, including those which may be added in the future. It is available as of [OpenSSH 7.2](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2). In fact, it even includes `no-pty`, even though I listed it separately for this answer.)*

Comment: Awesome. Afaiu the `no-pty` option is the safer way then (/preventing/ terminal control sequences?).

Comment: Most control sequences only make sense to the terminal itself, but the pty layer handles basic line-editing things such as CR ⇄ CRLF translation (expanding byte 0A to 0D 0A, or the other way around).

Comment: I've re-read your comment, and yes, in terms of data corruption, it is safer to disable PTY allocation server-side than rely on clients always getting it right. (You'll still want the clientside option to avoid the annoying warning message, though.)